# Is it possible to connect an Epson Receipt Printer (w/ an RJ-11 jack) to our router?

Tags: network-printer, cable

We have an Epson Receipt Printer (#TM-T88V) at our building. It has USB, serial, and RJ-11 ports (see picture). When we bought it, we wrongly assumed it had the common Ethernet (RJ-45) port on it.

Before purchasing the printer, we ran an Ethernet cable from our router in our office to the printer's installation location.

Will the printer connect to our network if we buy an adapter to allow the RJ-45 cable to be plugged in to the RJ-11 port?

[image: Preview of our Ethernet cable and Epson's RJ-11 port.]

Comment: To clarify, we need it to be connected to our network, due to the way our POS software is programmed. We can't use USB or serial.

Comment: The rj11 jack means it works with the phone network - you can't convert it to work on the Internet directly. There are some hacks (like using the Ethernet drop to connect to the phone line, or maybe, maybe using VoIP although this could be unreliable) but neither of these will allow you to give an internet connection to the device - as the interface is not designed for it.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You need an adapter for the printer to have a network port ready. Where the serial female connector is remark there is a screw, it's usually on those model to remove a controller card.

Check [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCnk7wOu51I) for how to install the adapter.

It seem a older device, just worth to mention that if the adapter is not available online, getting a new model might help, as new model have even WIFI available.

Answer (score 1):

i setup tills so can confirm that this isnt possible, basicaly the RJ11 you are referring to is not to communicate to printer, this is for Till to be connected to Printer so EPOS can sent a message via printer to Till to open.

RJ11 is only used to send a signal to till unit so it open and only pulses, not to receive any data.

Plus for printer you need drivers and through RJ11 you wont get drivers point blank.
You need to look for RECEIPT PRINTERS with BLUETOOTH OR NFC and they will fulfill your requirements, there are many in the market currently.